Use cropdetect to check blanking errors
cropdetect outputs the crop area for every frame.
I would like cropdetect with either ffprobe or ffmpeg to output only the frame where the crop is less than actual size of the video.
So for 1920x1080 video, cropdetect should only output crop that is less than 1920:1080:0:0
This way I can detect quickly if I left black bars on any video during my edit (during resize, pan, zoom, etc).
This is done with qctools but its overly complicated for this simple function.
